# Rails Render JSON - Session Lost?

Tags: ajax, json, session, cookies

i am trying to make some Ajax calls to an controller which responds with JSON.

```
if session[:user]
  render :json => "Some Data"
else
  render :json => "You are not logged in"
end
```

The first time this action gets called by an authed user everything is ok and `session[:user]` is `!= nil`.
The second time it gets called it is `nil`!

So it seems like rails is loosing it's session as soon as i do `render :json`. I figured out that within the first call rails overrides the `*_session`-cookie with a new one. As consequence of that rails doesn't know about the initial, authed, session.

If i don't render the response as JSON everything works fine.

How to force rails to set the same sessionid in JSON rendered pages as in normal views?

Comment: Tried multiple tutorials about this - still the same issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After six days of searching I finally made it:

Seems like rails destroys the session because of the missing `X-CSRF-Token` Header. I am adding this header now in in the `ajaxSend` Hook of JQuery:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
  var sid = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", sid);
});
```

It's working as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

I put that in beforeSend method:

```
function goAjax(urlAddress,dataObject,successFunction,errorFunction){
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: urlAddress,
              beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'));
              },
              dataType: "json",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              processData: false,
              data: JSON.stringify(dataObject),
              context: document.body,
              success: function(data,status){ successFunction(data,status);},
              error: function(data,status){ errorFunction()}
        });
    }
```

works great if you don't need to use other way of ajax request(in this way you should add beforeSend to all ajax requests)